# Customer Registration not working in Magento

Tags: magento

In my magento multi store view website, customer registration is not working in magento 1.9.2.0 in both store. I have added a line

```
 echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey');
```

in persistent/customer/form/register.phtml in my theme. Still while clicking on the submit button it redirects to the same page and account is not creating in store.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="hidden" 
       name="form_key"
       value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check your form action of create customer form it should be

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->helper('customer')->getRegisterPostUrl()?>" method="post" id="form-validate" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

to create a customer in database and the formkey as mentioned

```
  <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
```

should be in form tag of login customer.

Let me know it's working in your case ...